# The difficulty in displaying partial data from JSON

Tags: android, json, dialog, android-adapter

I take a series of data from the server in the form of JSON, which is as follows, and I then store them in a list, and then they show up with the Adapter in a Recycler View.

```
[
{
    "cat_id": 593,
    "title": "آلرژی و ایمونولوژی",
    "image_add": "http://pezeshk-yab.com/upload/job_add",
    "image": "http://pezeshk-yab.com/upload/job_cat/Allergy.svg",
    "sub_cat": [
        {
            "cat_id": 594,
            "cat_title": "متخصص",
            "cat_parent_fk": 593
        },
        {
            "cat_id": 595,
            "cat_title": "فوق تخصص",
            "cat_parent_fk": 593
        }
    ]
},
{
    "cat_id": 15,
    "title": "ارتوپد",
    "image_add": "http://pezeshk-yab.com/upload/job_add",
    "image": "http://pezeshk-yab.com/upload/job_cat/Orthopedic.svg",
    "sub_cat": [
        {
            "cat_id": 506,
            "cat_title": "متخصص",
            "cat_parent_fk": 15
        },
        {
            "cat_id": 507,
            "cat_title": "فوق تخصص",
            "cat_parent_fk": 15
        }
    ]
}]
```

Everything works fine up to here. Now, what I want is to display a dialog by clicking on any item in the Recycler to display just these two JSON parts:

```
"sub_cat": [
    {
        "cat_id": 594,
        "cat_title": "متخصص",
        "cat_parent_fk": 593
    },
    {
        "cat_id": 595,
        "cat_title": "فوق تخصص",
        "cat_parent_fk": 593
    }
]
```

To do this, I define the dialog in the adapter, and the problem is that now all of this section `{all sub_cat }` is shown in the dialog.
The codes for my adapter are as follows:

```
[![public class CatsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CatsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<Cats> list;

    CatsAdapter(Context context, List<Cats> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cat_index, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Cats cats = list.get(position);
        holder.txt_title.setText(cats.getTitle());
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Dialog dialog = new Dialog((Activity) context);
                String id = cats.getCat_id();
                Log.i("l", "onClick: " +id );
                List<Cats> catsList = new ArrayList<>();
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custompopup);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rec_dialog);
                DialogAdapter dialogAdapter = new DialogAdapter(context, list);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(dialogAdapter);

                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        ImageRequest.create(holder.image).setTargetUrl(cats.getImage()).execute();


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView image;
        TextView txt_title;
        CardView cardView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_cat);
            txt_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_cat);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            txt_title.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
}]
```

[image]

Parsing JSON code :

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        Cats cats = new Cats();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                        String cat_id = jsonObject.getString("cat_id");
                        String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                        String image_add = jsonObject.getString("image_add");
                        String image = jsonObject.getString("image");

                       JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("sub_cat");

                        for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                            String sub_cat_id = object.getString("cat_id");
                            String sub_cat_title = object.getString("cat_title");
                            String sub_parent_fk = object.getString("cat_parent_fk");
                            cats.setSub_cat_id(sub_cat_id);
                            cats.setCat_title(sub_cat_title);
                            cats.setCat_parent_fk(sub_parent_fk);
                        }


                        cats.setCat_id(cat_id);
                        cats.setTitle(title);
                        cats.setImage(image);
                        cats.setImage_add(image_add);
                        list.add(cats);
                        catsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why your are passing your whole list to the DialogAdapter ?

```
DialogAdapter dialogAdapter = new DialogAdapter(context, list);
```

if your want to show the child sub_cat of the category in the dialog you should just get the sub_cats from category and create a adapter with those sub_cats

---

this should be your Category Class :

```
public class Category {

    private Integer catId;
    private String title;
    private String imageAdd;
    private String image;
    private List<SubCat> subCat = null;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public Integer getCatId() {
        return catId;
    }

    public void setCatId(Integer catId) {
        this.catId = catId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getImageAdd() {
        return imageAdd;
    }

    public void setImageAdd(String imageAdd) {
        this.imageAdd = imageAdd;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public List<SubCat> getSubCat() {
        return subCat;
    }

    public void setSubCat(List<SubCat> subCat) {
        this.subCat = subCat;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

and subCategory class:

```
public class SubCat {

    private Integer catId;
    private String catTitle;
    private Integer catParentFk;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public Integer getCatId() {
        return catId;
    }

    public void setCatId(Integer catId) {
        this.catId = catId;
    }

    public String getCatTitle() {
        return catTitle;
    }

    public void setCatTitle(String catTitle) {
        this.catTitle = catTitle;
    }

    public Integer getCatParentFk() {
        return catParentFk;
    }

    public void setCatParentFk(Integer catParentFk) {
        this.catParentFk = catParentFk;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

and in your code do this :

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    Category category = new Category();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                    category.setCatId(jsonObject.getString("cat_id"));
                    category.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                    category.setImageAdd(jsonObject.getString("image_add"));
                    category.setImage(jsonObject.getString("image"));

                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("sub_cat");
                    category.setSubCat(new ArrayList<>());
                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        SubCat subCat = new SubCat();

                        subCat.setCatId(object.getString("cat_id"));
                        subCat.setCatTitle(object.getString("cat_title"));
                        subCat.setCatParentFk(object.getString("cat_parent_fk"));

                        category.getSubCat().add(subCat);
                    }

                    list.add(category);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            catsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

then when ever you need the subCategory of your category you can do like this :

```
Category cat=list.get(position);
ArrayList<SubCat> subCategories=cat.getSubCat();
```

Comment: @HadiKhezrpor here you are getting the category from your list Cats cats = list.get(position); then call the cats.getSubCategories() are you parsing your json with Gson or JsonOject ?

Comment: parsing by JsonObject

Comment: @HadiKhezrpor connect me on tlgram #amir_hossein_mirzaei_1